# Retrieve number of OP-RETURN transaction

Tags: bitcoin-core, python, timestamp, op-return

Is there a possible way to extract the bitcoin transaction protocoll with Python and extract specifically OP RETURN transaction? 
I want to plot the number of those over the course of time to derive some statistics from it.

Best regards
Nils

Answer (score 1):

For statistics you’re best using [bitcoin-iterate](https://github.com/rustyrussell/bitcoin-iterate) which will let you extract information very quickly. Here you want to be searching for scripts beginning with the op return byte, it takes only tens of minutes to search the whole chain from disk.